# Update single specific field only when using $ in embedded document Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Here's my snippet of code.

```
router.post(
  "/chapter/officers/edit/:id/:c_id",
  async (req, res) => {
    try {

      const updateChapter = await Council.findOneAndUpdate(
        { "chapters._id": req.params.c_id },
        {
          "chapters.$.officers": req.body,
        }
      );

      if (!updateChapter) return res.status(404).json({ msg: "Not found" });

      res.json("Edit Success");
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ msg: error.message });
    }
  }
);
```

I am planning on updating only one specific field at a time BUT when I tried to send this JSON from Postman

```
{
    "grandTriskelion": "sample"
}
```

The other filled in field values becomes an empty string. Heres an example of my res.json

```
 "_id": "5fc9cbb7ba7e2e2430c9a4d8",
        "name": "Maria Aurora",
        "code": "MA",
        "chapters": [
            {
                "officers": {
                    "grandTriskelion": "sample",
                    "deputyGrandTriskelion": "",
                    "masterWilderOfTheWhip": ""
                },
                "_id": "5fca014e49fa3f2910794bb8",
                "name": "Maria Aurora Community Based"
            }
        ],
```

I've hit a roadblock. I'm a beginner at MERN stack.

Comment: you need to do it manually like this `{ "chapters.$.officers.grandTriskelion": req.body.grandTriskelion }`, make one logic to produce this kind of string for update from your body params.

Comment: thats my first solution but instead it makes the other fields null.. thanks for the response though deeply appreciated.

Comment: It should work you can check [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jkXMKT_1vu8)